# My Asus Router 5Gz is not working

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have an Asus router with dual-band. Tried to connect to 5Ghz band with my wifi extender, but when I connect to it it says there is no internet connection.

I am connecting to the 5Ghz band with my phone and still says no internet, the 5Ghz is not a hidden network. It is broadcasting SSID. I've also tried to add manually so It connects to my specific SSID and AES key. But still not working. I decided to reset the whole thing but after setting it up it still won't work.

The white light is on for the 5Gz and confused why its not working

My router is an Asus RT-AC3100.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your phone is 5 GHz - many are 2.4 GHz.  Try connecting on the 2.4 GHz band.

Find a laptop (friend perhaps) with an AC wireless card. Try hooking up this laptop to the 5 GHz band.

See if the above works